# How to smooth stream Rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a Rxjs:

```
   private loading = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

The `loading` can be changed fast from `true` to `false`. How to smooth this stream and pass values only if time between **false** and **true** is more then 3 seconds, otherwise pass false by default?

Comment: You want to emit `true` only if time between `false` to `true` is more than 3 seconds, otherwise emit `false` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Megan you can check out the following demo, I think it will help you sort out the issue you are facing. (I'm using 1500ms instead of 3000ms but it doesn't matter that much)

So the first part of the issue is that you want to be able to get info about past states of the loading state (the value that is stored in the `BehavourSubject`) at a certain interval.

This is achieved by the combination of the `buffer` operator and `interval` observable. The idea is that the `buffer` will record all events emitted trough the stream and pass them on whenever the observable that is passed as it's argument emits a value (in our case each 1500 ms the `interval` observable will emit new value)

So each 1500ms we will get new value from the loading subject.

The next thing that we need to handle is to guarantee that the subject has been unchanged for the past 1500ms, the way that I had achieve that is by using the `scan` operator to store the last emitted values from the subject.

With this aggregated data in the follow up `filter` operator I'am checking if there had been any new values written in the subject (if there were any they would've been accessible trough the `newEvents` variable, which will be an array of the last buffered Subject values)

So the filter condition pretty much states that if there are no events for the past 1500ms, the latest loading value should be passed.

At the end of the pipe `distinctUntilChanged` is used to filter out any duplicated states of loading, so only when new load/loaded state is present, the values in the HTML is changed.

```js
let {
  BehaviorSubject,
  interval
} = rxjs
let {
  buffer,
  scan,
  map,
  filter,
  distinctUntilChanged
} = rxjs.operators

let someFlagToSaveTheCurrentState = false;
let currentState = document.getElementById('currentState')

let loading = document.getElementById('loading')
let loadingBtn = document.getElementById('loadingbtn')

let loader = new BehaviorSubject(false)

loadingBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  someFlagToSaveTheCurrentState = !someFlagToSaveTheCurrentState;
  loader.next(someFlagToSaveTheCurrentState);

  currentState.innerHTML = someFlagToSaveTheCurrentState;
})

let interval$ = interval(1500)

loader.pipe(
  buffer(interval$),
  scan((acc,e) => ([...acc.slice(1),e]), [[false], [false]]),
  filter(([lastEvents, newEvents]) => newEvents.length === 0 && lastEvents.length !== 0),
  map(([lastEvents, newEvents]) => {
  let result = false;
  if (newEvents.length === 0 && lastEvents.length !== 0) {
    result = lastEvents[lastEvents.length - 1]
  }
  return result;
}),
distinctUntilChanged()
  
).subscribe((loadingState) => {
  console.log(loadingState)
  if (loadingState) {
    loading.innerHTML = 'Element loading'
  } else {
    loading.innerHTML = 'Element is loaded'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>

<h1 id="loading">Loading</h1>

<button id="loadingbtn">Toggle loading</button>
<h1 id="currentState">false</h1>
```

### Try running the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use `debounceTime()` to have your stream wait for a given duration before emitting a value. (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime)

To still have a default value be emitted *directly* when you subscribe to the stream you will have to prepend your (debounced) stream with a default value using `startWith()` (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith)

```
const $loadingState = loading
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(5 * 1000),
    startWith(false)
  );
```